# Python GET Request returns data when tried on Postman but the generated python code not working

Tags: python, python-requests

I have this URL that works on Postman and returns data:

```
https://www.tablebuilder.singstat.gov.sg/api/table/resourceid?isTestApi=true&keyword=manufacturing&searchoption=all
```

But the Python code generated on Postman does not work.

```
import requests
url = "https://www.tablebuilder.singstat.gov.sg/api/table/resourceid?isTestApi=true&keyword=manufacturing&searchoption=all"
response = requests.request("GET", url)
print(response.text)
```

What could the reason be? This code used to work in the past. Is there a permanent fix for the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to provide a User-Agent HTTP header.

For example:

```
import requests
import json

url = "https://www.tablebuilder.singstat.gov.sg/api/table/resourceid"
params = {
    "isTestApi": "true",
    "keyword": "manufacturing",
    "searchoption": "all"
}
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 14_4_1) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/17.3.1 Safari/605.1.15"
}

with requests.get(url, params=params, headers=headers) as response:
    response.raise_for_status()
    print(json.dumps(response.json(), indent=2))
```

Comment: What is the need to provide User Agent HTTP header? Is the data provider trying to collect our user data?

Comment: @prashanthmanohar I recommend [this documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent)